# Which communication protocol to use in a ServiceStack multi-tier architecture

Tags: c#, servicestack

We're planning our system to have a set of publicly accessible services which call into a set of internal services, all implemented using ServiceStack.

My question is, what is the best method (in terms of performance, stability and code maintanability) for this cross-service communication?

E.g. should my public services call the internal services using a ServiceStack client or use the Rabbit / Redis messaging system? And if the latter, can I call two or more internal services asynchronously and await for the response from both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-way communications [Messaging offers a lot of benefits](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging#benefits-of-message-queues) where if installing a [Rabbit MQ Broker](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) is an option, [Rabbit MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ) provides the more industrial strength option.

For request/reply services where requests are transient and both endpoints are required to be up, the typed [C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) allow for more direct/debuggable point-to-point communications with less moving parts.

Using the clients async API's let you easily make multiple calls in parallel, e.g:

```
//fire off to 2 async requests simultaneously...
var task1 = client.GetAsync(new Request1 { ... });
var task2 = client.GetAsync(new Request2 { ... });

//additional processing if any...

//Continue when first response is received
var response1 = await task1;

//Continue after 2nd response, if it arrived before task1, call returns instantly
var response2 = await task1;
```

The above code continues after Request1 is completed, you can also use [Task.WhenAny()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx) to process which ever request was completed first.